# Why do I get this following error in python(discord bot): TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, bots, typeerror, discord

I'm currently writing a discord bot and I can't seem to understand why the str object is not callable. response.text is grabbing the content provided from an api

```
answer=response.text()
print("user balance"+answer)
msg=answer.format(message)
```

Error I get

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Boss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/Boss/Desktop/python/lol.py", line 28, in on_message
    answer=response.text()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: What is `response` ?

Comment: Its from my api request.            `response = requests.post(https:api.com) `@Kingsley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*string object is not callable* means `text` is a string and thus not callable.

So just remove the brackets:

```
answer = response.text
```

Comment: When I remove the brackets, I get another error. @dan

Comment: `user balance{"balance":"15","currency":"USD"}
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Boss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/Boss/Desktop/python/lol.py", line 30, in on_message
    msg=answer.format(message)
KeyError: '"balance"'`

Comment: @JohnMckhay Yeah so `answer` is now a JSON string. I'm not sure what you're trying to do. But you might want to decode that JSON.

Comment: Oh okay, how would I do that exactly? I tried to create a load `        answer=response.text
        data = json.load(answer)
        print(data)` but no success

Comment: It's `json.loads`

Comment: Oh my god I managed to do it, that is all thanks to you @dan  I'm really thankful. Thank you so much. Your tips lead me in the right direction

Comment: @JohnMckhay Glad it worked. Feel free to upvote the answer too.

Comment: @JohnMckhay Actually, come to think about it. You should be able to do `requests.json()` instead of `requests.text`. That way you don't have to decode it with `json.loads()`

Comment: requests.jsons() dont exist did you mean response.json()? I just put that and it didn't work. `answer=response.json() 
        print(answer)
        msg=answer.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)`

Comment: `{'balance': '4.973520', 'currency': 'USD'} Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Boss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/Boss/Desktop/python/lol.py", line 34, in on_message
    msg=answer.format(message)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'format'`

Comment: It's hard to keep you updated on the situation o.o via stack.  But yeah I just fixed it and works fine :D

Comment: @JohnMckhay So you fixed it? I think you just need `msg=response.json()`